# How to tell Glassfish to retain the compiled JSPs?

Tags: java, glassfish

I have tried the below setting:

```
 <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
```

But it is giving me the below error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of '{"http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":taglib, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":jsp-property-group}' is expected.
```

Is there any other setting? I Want to check the compiled class files or .java files that are generated out of jsps.

GlassFish version is 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after some more research I got this. First, I have placed the above snippet in web.xml of my webapp, instead, it should be under the default-web.xml file in the domain's config directory. And it should not be under `<jsp-config>` but under `<init-param>`. So, the actual setting should be like:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Make the changes and restart the server. You will be able to view the generated java files (generated from the JSPs) in `%GF_HOME%\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\...` directory.

Also, GlassFish does not generate the java files for all the JSPs. You must open the required JSP in the web browser only then will GlassFish generate the corresponding java file.

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beaej/index.html) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/i_want_to_see_my).